# iOS Simulator Crash in xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, simulator, xcode5.1

Simulator crash occurs frequently while running app and also using in build app like maps , safari , settings etc.. .

The error response is shared below

```
Process:         iPhone Simulator [2454]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode 5.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone Simulator
Identifier:      com.apple.iphonesimulator
Version:         7.1 (463.9.41)
Build Info:      Indigo-463009041000000~2
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [182]
Responsible:     iPhone Simulator [2454]
User ID:         850824327

Date/Time:       2014-07-30 14:47:41.082 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.3 (13D65)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  F291053A-A0B0-6AF4-1BF0-5D6C2199246F


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000001

VM Regions Near 0x1:
--> 
    __TEXT                 00000001082b4000-00000001082f2000 [  248K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode 5.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone Simulator

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88f2a702 -[NSThemeFrame
```

Comment: when u getting while launch?

Answer (score 0):

Reset Content and Settings of your simulator and try again. If it doesn't work try this : delete the derived data from Xcode folder in this path : user/lib/xcode/derived data.

Comment: Awesome  ... Resetting the content & settings of simultor works fine without crash ..:-)                                                   Thank you